# Problema reproductor java

Tags: java, interfaz-gráfica

El problema es que al iniciar la reproducción la barra de progreso no avanza, tampoco el segundero. En cambio, si pulso el botón de pausa y reanudo la reproducción, la barra y el progreso sí se refrescan y funcionan como deben. No se si se trata de algún error con el evento `changeListener` al interactuar con el slider.

Os adjunto unas capturas de pantalla para que podáis ver mejor lo que pasa:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto también el código. La primera clase, Reproductor,  es la encargada de crear la gui:

```
        /*
     * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
     * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
     * and open the template in the editor.
     */
    package reproductordiu;

    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.io.File;
    import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
    import javax.sound.sampled.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
    import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

    /**
     *
     * @author ignacioaranguren
     */
    public class Reproductor extends JFrame {

        private int h = 100, w = 300, x = 0, y = 99;

        private JButton reproducir, abrir, pausar, stop;
        private ImageIcon botonReproducir, botonPausa, botonAbrir, botonStop;
        private JPanel panelPrincipal;
        protected JSlider barraRepro;
        private Clip clip;
        private File audio;
        private boolean flag = false;
        private JLabel etiqueta = new JLabel();

        public Reproductor() {
            setTitle("Movimiento");
            setSize(w, h);
            setResizable(false);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setVisible(true);
            panelPrincipal = new JPanel();
            reproducir = new JButton();
            pausar = new JButton();
            abrir = new JButton();
            stop = new JButton();
            botonReproducir = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("../imagenes/icons8-reproducir-en-cÃ­rculo-48.png"));
            reproducir.setIcon(botonReproducir);
            reproducir.setEnabled(false);

            reproducir.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
                    Thread audio = new Thread(new HiloReproductor(clip, barraRepro, etiqueta));
                    audio.start();  
                    pausar.setEnabled(true);
                    barraRepro.setEnabled(true);
                    stop.setEnabled(true);
                    reproducir.setEnabled(false);

                }
            });

            botonStop = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("../imagenes/icons8-detener-64.png"));
            stop.setIcon(botonStop);
            stop.setEnabled(false);
            stop.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
                    clip.stop();
                    pausar.setEnabled(false);
                    stop.setEnabled(false);
                    barraRepro.setEnabled(false);
                    reproducir.setEnabled(false);
                    etiqueta.setText("0s/0s");

                }
            });

            botonPausa = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("../imagenes/icons8-pausa-en-cÃ­rculo-48.png"));
            pausar.setIcon(botonPausa);
            pausar.setEnabled(false);
            pausar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
                    clip.stop();
                    reproducir.setEnabled(true);
                }
            });

            botonAbrir = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("../imagenes/icons8-abrir-carpeta-48.png"));
            abrir.setIcon(botonAbrir);
            abrir.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
                    flag = false;
                    reproducir.setEnabled(true);
                    JFileChooser file = new JFileChooser();
                    file.showOpenDialog(abrir);
                    audio = file.getSelectedFile();
                    try {
                        clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                        AudioInputStream sound = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(audio);
                        clip.open(sound);
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR\n" + "No hay fichero de audio o no es de" + "audio", "alerta", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    }
                }
            });

            barraRepro = construyeBarraProgreso(x, y);
            barraRepro.setEnabled(false);
            barraRepro.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                    JSlider source = (JSlider) e.getSource();
                    if (source.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
                        pack();
                        int a = barraRepro.getValue();
                        System.out.println("Posicion barra = " + a);
                        System.out.println("Duración total = " + clip.getMicrosecondLength());
                        System.out.println("Actual = " + clip.getMicrosecondPosition());
                        System.out.println((a * clip.getMicrosecondLength()) / 100);
                        System.out.println("\n");
                        clip.setMicrosecondPosition((a * clip.getMicrosecondLength()) / 100);

                    }
                }
            });



            panelPrincipal.add(abrir);
            panelPrincipal.add(reproducir);
            panelPrincipal.add(pausar);
            panelPrincipal.add(stop);
            panelPrincipal.add(barraRepro);
            panelPrincipal.add(etiqueta);
            add(panelPrincipal);
            pack();
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setVisible(true);
            setResizable(true);
            setSize(574,93);
        }

        private JSlider construyeBarraProgreso(int min, int max) {
            JSlider progreso = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, min, max, 0);
            progreso.setPaintTicks(true);
            progreso.setMajorTickSpacing(30);

            return progreso;
        }

    }
```

La segunda, HiloReproductor, es la encargada de controlar el avance del archivo de audio, para que se muestre se la barra de progreso.

```
package reproductordiu;

import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
/**
 *
 * @author ignacio
 */
public class HiloReproductor implements Runnable {

    private Clip clip;
    private JSlider barraRepro;
    private JLabel etiqueta;
    public HiloReproductor(Clip clip, JSlider barraRepro, JLabel etiqueta) {
        this.clip = clip;
        this.barraRepro = barraRepro;
        this.etiqueta = etiqueta;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        clip.start();
        float duracionClip = clip.getMicrosecondLength();
        while (clip.isRunning() == true) {
            float avance = clip.getMicrosecondPosition();
            float posicion = (100 * avance) / duracionClip;
            barraRepro.setValue((int) posicion);
            etiqueta.setText(Long.toString(clip.getMicrosecondPosition()/1000000) + "s"+"/"+clip.getMicrosecondLength()/1000000+"s");
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Desafortunadamente así no funciona esta interfaz. Cuando hacemos estos cambios, debemos repintarla; en este caso, después de quitar y poner el JSlider actualizado.

```
f.remove(slider);
double timeNow=(durationInSeconds*clip.getFramePosition())/frames;
slider.setValue((int)Math.round(timeNow));
f.add(slider);
f.repaint();
```

Como guía, un [hilo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15855533/how-to-update-jslider-with-an-audio-file-as-progress-bar) muy similar en SO en inglés.

Además, estás creando un nuevo hilo cada vez que le das Reproducir. Claro que se va a actualizar con el nuevo dato de en qué va la reproducción. En ninguna parte estás actualizando eso porque crees que con el while isRunning lo va a hacer. Como cuentan en el hilo referencia, pareciera saturarse y termina actualizando cada *muchos* segundos. Usa un Timer que actualice el estado del slider cada n milisegundos (30?)

Comment: Vamos, que debo repintarla una vez inicialice la reproducción. ¿Sí?

Comment: Cada vez que vayas a refrescar el estado del Slider, repintar. Sí.

Comment: ¿Y si repinto el mismo slider cada vez que avance la reproducción?

Comment: No soluciona nada. Tampoco creo que se ese el problema, ya que la barra sí se actualiza, pero después de pulsar pausa y seguidamente pulsando reanudar, como se ve en el video. Aun así, gracias!